# Modal box "hidden" behind greyed out area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, pagedown

Im following along with http://multiplethreads.wordpress.com/tag/pagedown/
The example in the link above makes use of twitter bootstrap whereas i make use of zurb foundation.
Basically im trying to get a custom dialog box to insert images from my pagedown editior (sort of like how stackoverflow does it).

Im abale to pull up the modal box (foundation reveal) but it seems to be "behind" something and i cant seem to interact with it. Any ideas?

My code:
js file:

```
PH.ui.markdown = {
  initialize: function () {
    var markdownTextArea = $('textarea[data-markdown=true]');
    if (markdownTextArea.length == 1) {
      markdownTextArea.addClass('wmd-input')
        .wrap("<div class='wmd-panel' />")
        .before("<div id='wmd-button-bar'></div>")
        .after("<div id='wmd-preview' class='wmd-preview'></div>"); 
      var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
      var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
editor.hooks.set("insertImageDialog", function (callback) {     
      //setTimeout(function () {
      $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
     // }, 5000);
     return true; // tell the editor that we'll take care of getting the image url
    });
      editor.run();
    }
  }
};
```

html:

```
  <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
                      <h2>Upload Image</h2>    
                           <%= f.file_field :image %>
                      <button class="btn" id="insert_image_post">Insert Image</button>
                     <!--  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a> -->
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see your code (e.g css, views etc), show your code instead screenshoot.

Comment: You almost certainly have a `z-index` CSS problem.

Comment: Hi, i posted the question quite quickly (was the first iteration :-D - ive updated it though. Left me know what you think.

Comment: You're welcome, now you know what a z-index problem looks like :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The wmd-prompt-background had a z-index of 1000:

```
<div class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 1000; opacity: 0.5; height: 1085px; left: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

So i just added:

```
<style type="text/css">
#myModal {
  z-index: 1500;
}
</style>
```

to my page and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to position the div of your modal directly under the `<body>`. This way you make sure that the modal is not part of elements with special `z-index`